# Groovy: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'double'. Try 'java.lang.Double' instead

Tags: java, groovy

I have this code for a system which accepts only groovy for customization, but every time I try to submit my form it returns this error:

> **Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'double'. Try 'java.lang.Double' instead**

```
try {
    double valorOriginal = (double) fieldChanges.getFieldChange(MetafieldIdFactory.valueOf("customFlexFields.rateCustomDFF_rate_amount_original"))?.newValue;
    double porcentagem = (double) fieldChanges.getFieldChange(MetafieldIdFactory.valueOf("customFlexFields.rateCustomDFF_desconto_percentual"))?.newValue;
    double rateAmount = fieldChanges.getFieldChange(MetafieldIdFactory.valueOf("rateAmount"))?.newValue;
    boolean flagDesconto = (boolean) fieldChanges.getFieldChange(MetafieldIdFactory.valueOf("customFlexFields.rateCustomDFF_flag_desconto_percentual"))?.newValue;

    if (porcentagem >= 100)
        throw BizFailure.createProgrammingFailure("Desconto nao pode ser igual ou superior a 100!");
    if (valorOriginal == null || valorOriginal <= 0)
        throw BizFailure.createProgrammingFailure("Favor informar o valor original");

    if(flagDesconto == true){
        rateAmount = valorOriginal - (valorOriginal * porcentagem)/100;
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    throw BizFailure.createProgrammingFailure(ex.getMessage().toString());
}
```

Comment: double is a primitive type. primitive types can't be null

Comment: What stultuske said. Try using `Double` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (and as the error message itself states), the error is that your possibly-null properties are being assigned to the primitive type `double`, which can't be null.

If you use the boxed type `Double`, that'll solve the problem since `Double` can be null.

```
Double n = null; // no problem
double n = null; // Cannot cast object 'null' with class ...
```

As an aside, this error can arise in other cases, such as forgetting a return value, which implicitly returns null from a function that's declared to return a primitive type:

```
static double gonnaFail() {
  // Cannot cast object 'null' with class ...
}
```